# R Shiny. No applicable method for 'mutate' applied to an object of class "c('reactiveExpr', 'reactive', 'function')"

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, dplyr

I am trying to create a very simple Shiny app that could let a user select a set of tables and see which variables are shared by those tables.

My input data (named "df" in my code below) looks like this:

| Tables | Variables |
| --- | --- |
| tabla_1 | A |
| tabla_1 | Z |
| tabla_1 | Y |
| tabla_1 | V |
| tabla_1 | B |
| tabla_2 | H |
| tabla_2 | B |
| tabla_2 | A |
| tabla_2 | U |
| tabla_3 | U |
| tabla_3 | S |
| tabla_3 | M |
| tabla_4 | U |
| tabla_4 | A |
| tabla_4 | B |
| tabla_4 | V |
| tabla_4 | Q |
| tabla_4 | O |
| tabla_4 | F |

If the user selected all the tables available to compare them, the output would have to look like this (mytable1 in my code below):

| Variables | tabla_1 | tabla_2 | tabla_3 | tabla_4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | Yes | Yes | No | Yes |
| Z | Yes | No | No | No |
| Y | Yes | No | No | No |
| V | Yes | No | No | Yes |
| B | No | Yes | No | Yes |
| H | No | Yes | No | No |
| U | No | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| S | No | Yes | Yes | No |
| M | No | No | Yes | No |
| Q | No | No | No | Yes |
| O | No | No | No | Yes |
| F | No | No | No | Yes |

Right now my code looks like this:

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)



ui <- fluidPage(
  title = "Compare Data Tables",
  
    sidebarPanel(
        
        checkboxGroupInput("show_tables", "Tables to compare",
                           unique(df$Tables), selected = unique(df$Tables)
                           
                           ),
        
        mainPanel("comparison", DT::dataTableOutput("mytable1"))))

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  
  
  filter1 <- reactive({subset(df, Tables == input$show_tables)})
  
  result<-filter1 %>% 
           mutate(n = "Yes")%>%
           pivot_wider(names_from = Tables, values_from = n, values_fill = list(n = "No"))
  
  output$mytable1 <- DT::renderDataTable({
    DT::datatable(result)
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

After I run that I get this message:

> Error in UseMethod("mutate") :    no applicable method for 'mutate'
> applied to an object of class "c('reactiveExpr', 'reactive',
> 'function')"

I am not sure what might be wrong. Is it that I cannot use the mutate function to a reactive object. If so, what could I use instead to get the same output?

Thanks a lot for any suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could change the `server` part to

```
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  
  
  result <- reactive({
    
    req(input$show_tables)
    tmp <- subset(df, Tables %in% input$show_tables)
  
  tmp %>% 
    dplyr::mutate(n = "Yes")%>%
    tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = Tables, values_from = n, values_fill = list(n = "No"))
  })
  output$mytable1 <- DT::renderDataTable({
    DT::datatable(result())
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

-output

[image]

Comment: Hey! This is great. Thanks. Just one question. What is req(input$show_tables) for in this case?

Comment: @AFS It is when you there was no selection made.  I guess you already have a default selection